# Como retornar os objects num many to many Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

Considere o modelo

```
class Dealership(models.Model):
    dealership = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Ordered(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey("Customer")
    dealership = models.ManyToManyField("Dealership")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=status_list, default='p')
```

Eu tentei

```
$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from new_way.core.models import Ordered, Dealership
>>> q = Ordered.objects.all()[:5]
>>> [i.dealership for i in q.dealership.all]
```

Gerou o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'dealership'
```

How to return

```
Ordered.dealership.dealership
```

all dealership by Ordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro diz que `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'dealership'`. Você está na realidade fazendo isso:

```
ordens = Ordered.objects.all().dealership.all()
```

Para o código funcionar corretamente você deve fazer um loop com as ordens e aí sim fazer um segundo loop.

```
lista = []
ordens = Ordered.objects.all()
for ordem in ordens:
    for o in ordem.dealership.all():
        lista.append(o.dealership)
```

ou

```
lista = [o.dealership for o in ordem.dealership.all() for ordem in Ordered.objects.all()]
```

Comment: eu não queria misturar os posts, mas em http://stackoverflow.com/a/30858064/802542 porque não funciona do jeito que eu havia feito antes? Tem que usar 2 loops mesmo? Mas de qualquer forma funcionou. Obrigado.

Comment: Seu código não funciona porque você estava tentando pegar um atributo de uma `queryset` e não do objeto, por isso foi necessário fazer um loop dos objetos filtrados e depois um outro loop dos objetos do campo `manytomanyfield`

Comment: um manyTomany sempre funciona assim para iteração? Porque eu não achei isso na documentação?

Comment: @RegisdaSilva sempre funciona assim, certamente tem na documentação a explicação, talvez não esteja claro.

Comment: +1 eu só sugeriria fazer um `prefetch_related` pra evitar uma consulta SQL adicional por cada iteração desse *loop* (acho que o `prefetch_related` funciona pra `ManyToManyField`, ou estou enganado?).

Comment: @Orion só mais uma coisinha: `print([o.dealership__address for o in order.dealership.all()])` ou `print([o.dealership.address for o in order.dealership.all()])` não foi. Não retornou o endereço.

Comment: @mgibsonbr não sei te informar, nunca usei `prefetch_related`, vou até dar uma olhada na documentação depois

Comment: @RegisdaSilva não seria `o.address`?

Comment: @Orion acho que to desaprendendo rsrs Thanks again.

Comment: @Orion Funciona sim! Veja [esse código no pastebin](http://pastebin.com/UJdMxLx4): fiz a mesma consulta duas vezes, para um mesmo conjunto de `4` `Ordered`; sem o `prefetch_related` ele fez `5` *queries* (`1` para os `Ordered`s e `1` para cada `Ordered` retornado pela primeira *query* - se fossem `1000` resultados ele faria `1000` *queries*); com o `prefetch_related` ele só fez `2` queries (`1` para os `Ordered`s e `1` para achar os `Dealership`s de todos os resultados de uma vez só - se fossem `1000` resultados ainda seria uma única *query*). Diferença significativa na performance! :)